# Learning Django: Internal error 500, Invalid command 'PythonHandler'

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.6

I am trying to run a Django project "strona".
I did create  a folder structure in ~/apps, created symbolic links and added in .httpd.conf of ~/apps:

```
SetHandler None
```

And in .httpd.conf of my public_html:

```
SetHandler python-program

PythonHandler django.core.handlers.wsgi # also tried modpython modpython

SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE strona.settings

PythonPath "['/usr/local/lib/python2.6', '/home/USERNAME/apps'] + sys.path"
PythonDebug On
#PythonDebug Off
```

In error.log I get this:

```
[Date] [alert] [client [...]] /[...]/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PythonHandler', Perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I do have Python and Djano, I can import wsgi module.
Why is it not working?

Comment: This is an issue on the “Apache side”. See [Why do I get error, Invalid command 'PythonHandler'?](http://serverfault.com/q/57505/128232)

Comment: Thank You, but I've got no /etc/apache2/mods anabled directory. In fact, I've got no directory there at all, just conf.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got the instruction to use PythonHandler, but it is completely wrong. That's only used for mod_python, which has been deprecated for years and is no longer supported by Django.

However, if you are just learning Django, you should not be trying to run it with Apache. That's for deployment: for learning, you should use the built-in development server, as described in the tutorial. When you *are* ready to set up Apache for real, you should read the very comprehensive deployment documentation to learn how to configure mod_wsgi, which is what you should actually be using.